# ASP.NET MVC form wizard prevent user skipping wizard step (Controller Action) using URL bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, actionresult

I’m currently working on a very large form. I thought it would be a good idea to section the form by implementing a form wizard (multiple views/action results) to improve the user experience.

One requirement is that the user must complete a small eligibility test that ensures they meet the minimum requirements prior to starting the application wizard itself.

Having done nothing like this before I can only see one approach to this problem and that is using a flag e.g IsEligible in a session that determines if the user can access the form wizard view/s. Let’s say my controller has two ActionResults  (Eligibility and WizardStepOne) that server separate views. For example:

**Controller - Untested Code**

```
public ActionResult Eligibility()
{
   Return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Eligibility(EligibilityViewModel model)
{
   if(!ModelState.IsValid)
   {
      return View(model);
   }

   Session["IsEligible"] = true;

   return("Success");
}

public ActionResult WizardStepOne()
{
   bool stuff = (bool)Session["stuff"];

   if(IsEligible == null)
   {
      return("Eligibility");
   }

   return RedirectToAction("Eligibility");
}
```

In short if the user attempts access the first step of the wizard and the IsEligible flag hasn't been set by the Eligibility post action then the user get redirected back to the eligibility form.

I've also looked into action filters but couldn't make much sense of it. I'll also have to implement this functionality at a later stage to prevent users skipping between wizard steps using the url e.g skipping WizardStepOne and starting at WizardStepTwo.

Is there a better approach then one described above in this situation? I'd rather avoid using a session as restarting the form becomes problematic as it would require a restart button to abandon the session especially between wizard steps.

Answer (score 0):

What you are mentioning sounds like you might make use of some simple state machine to define valid steps through your form. So, when user is at stage 3. for example, you will check if he came from step 2 or not. For each step for particular user and session > you can save some hash value in his session. That way they could make no use typing in url directly.

Comment: Interesting. Can you provide an example?